# Change aspect ratio of camera in Graphics3d?

Tags: graphics3d

The funtion Graphics3D has the option to set the position and orientation of the camera. But the image seen by the cammera is always a square. Is it posible to change this? The following pictures should clarify my question.

As shown by Graphics3D:

[image]

What I need:

[image]

Comment: [`AspectRatio`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AspectRatio.html)?